# (VueJS) TinyMCE Error : Cannot read property 'getContent' of null

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, wysiwyg

Ok, so i'm working on wysiwyg editor with tinymce in vuejs. Everythings work fine until i put a v-model on tinymce html tag. The value of v-model is get from loadData method (from api), so it will update the value when the data is loaded from api. It always show error "Cannot read property 'getContent' of null" but, even though it always get error, sometimes the value from  loadData method is loaded in tinyMCE editor, but sometimes is not loaded. So, what happened here ? Is something wrong in my code ?

(Below is the html code)

```
<div v-show="sideMenuIndex == 11">
<h1>Descriptions (Bio)</h1>
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column col-10">
            <tinymce :toolbar1="'undo redo | bold italic'" v-model="form.bio"></tinymce>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Below is the vue.js initial code)

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#form-place',
data: {
    sideMenuIndex: 0,
    search: '',
    bio: 'Ini adalah testing',
    form: {
        _id: null,
        name: '',
        slug: '',
        city: 'bandung',
        address: '',
        categories: [],
        menu_categories: [],
        parkir: '',
        bio: '',
        is_draft: true,
        is_partner: false,
        is_halal: true,
        is_sticker: false,
        photo: null,
        cuisines: [],
        payments: [],
        facilities: [],
        covid: [],
        galleries: [],
        operational_times: [
            {day: 'Senin', openTime: '00:00', closeTime: '00:00', is_open: true, is_24Hours: false},
            {day: 'Selasa', openTime: '00:00', closeTime: '00:00', is_open: true, is_24Hours: false},
            {day: 'Rabu', openTime: '00:00', closeTime: '00:00', is_open: true, is_24Hours: false},
            {day: 'Kamis', openTime: '00:00', closeTime: '00:00', is_open: true, is_24Hours: false},
            {day: 'Jumat', openTime: '00:00', closeTime: '00:00', is_open: true, is_24Hours: false},
            {day: 'Sabtu', openTime: '00:00', closeTime: '00:00', is_open: true, is_24Hours: false},
            {day: 'Minggu', openTime: '00:00', closeTime: '00:00', is_open: true, is_24Hours: false},
        ],
        call_to_actions: [
            {type: "gmaps", value: '', draft: false},
            {type: "whatsapp", value: '', draft: false},
            {type: "instagram", value: '', draft: false},
            {type: "web", value: '', draft: false},
            {type: "grabfood", value: '', draft: false},
            {type: "gofood", value: '', draft: false},
            {type: "checkin", value: '', draft: false},
            {type: "linkmenu", value: '', draft: false},
        ],
        payment_detail: []
    },
```

(Below is, the loadData method code)

```
 loadPlace: async function () {
        if (!placeId) return;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        if (urlParams.get('nav'))
            this.sideMenuIndex = urlParams.get('nav')
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`/api/v1/places/${placeId}`);
            const data = await res.json();
            this.form = data.data;
            this.options.data = 'https://emam.id/qr/' + this.form.slug;
            this.form.categories = this.form.categories.map(e => ({id: e.id, text: e.name}));
            this.form.payments = this.form.payments.map(e => ({code: e.code, text: e.name}));
            if (this.form.parkir)
                this.form.parkir = this.form.parkir.id;
            this.formFieldValues.payments = this.form.payments;
            this.loadGalleriesFromData();
            this.loadPhotoFromData();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
```

(Picture when v-model value not loaded)
[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaswX.png)

Picture when v-model value loaded
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oZkf.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an issue with the `vue-easy-tinymce` code you are using:

https://github.com/m3esma/vue-easy-tinymce/issues/3

...but I would note that code has not received an update in 3 years so it may not be maintained any longer.

TinyMCE provides its own Vue wrapper that is actively maintained so I would recommend switching to that component instead:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/